# Converting drawable to string to pass to another activity

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable, sharedpreferences

I'm currently trying to convert a drawable to a string and pass it to another activity via shared preferences using this method. ***loadIcon*** is a **Drawable**.

***Activity 1***

```
try {
    ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(pInfo.packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
} 
catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    loadIcon = ai.loadIcon(pm);

    Log.i("Icon drawable", loadIcon.toString());
                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("ANALYZE_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("drawable", loadIcon.toString());
                editor.commit();
```

This is what i get in Logcat:

```
11-06 10:13:28.995: I/Drawable shared(16786): android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@417f2aa8
```

Trying to retrieve it in the other activity

***Activity 2***

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ANALYZE_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
String drawableString = settings.getString("drawable", ""); 
Log.i("Drawable shared", drawableString);
Drawable drawableImage = getDrawable(drawableString);
imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawableImage);

       public Drawable getDrawable(String bitmapUrl) {
              try {
                URL url = new URL(bitmapUrl);
                Drawable d =new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream()));
                Log.i("d value", "d value " + d);
                return d; 
              }
              catch(Exception ex) {
                  Log.i("Null", "Drawable returns null");
                  return null;
              }
       }
```

I get a null when trying to convert it back to a drawable

Logcat:

```
11-06 10:13:28.995: I/Null(16786): Drawable returns null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i too face the same problem i do like this way..

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
String ba1=Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
```

> Then send this string to other activity.
>     then decode this Base64 code...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're passing `android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@417f2aa8` as the string, then attempting to use it as a `URL` object. You cannot create a `URL` from this data.

To be honest, I'm not sure why you're trying to do this. Both `Activity` objects are run from the same context and have the same icon. Why try to save it in preferences and load it immediately when you can just fetch the icon in the second `Activity`?

You're going to have to switch your implementation somehow; `Drawable`s do not all have `URL`s.

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve the icons of other Applications not my current activity

Comment: @rexer You should still be able to get the package info in the second `Activity`.

Comment: I did that instead, but i get another problem. loadIcon is actually still a BitmapDrawable but Android retrieves it as a Drawable so i'm unable to set it to my imageView via setImageDrawable

Comment: `setImageDrawable` takes a `Drawable`, why wouldn't you be able to set it?